# Getting Error: "No such container" using docker cp command

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, cp

I trying to copy a file from a container to my local machine.

As you can see below, my container is runnig...
`❯ docker ps`

| CONTAINER ID | IMAGE | COMMAND | CREATED | STATUS | PORTS | NAMES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1cbed27defce | postgres | "docker-entrypoint.s…" | 17 months ago | Up 44 minutes | 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp | pg |

When I use the `docker cp` command, I have this output...

```sh
❯ sudo docker cp pg:recom.bkp /home/melnik/dev/recom                  
[sudo] senha para melnik: 
Error response from daemon: No such container: pg
```

I've already tried the command `docker exec pg pwd` to get the correct path, but the output is just `/`

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: Does it work if you use the container id? `docker cp 1cbed27defce:recom.bkp /home/melnik/dev/recom`

Comment: Are you using Docker Desktop?  Since `sudo` changes your user identity and home directory, it's possible that `docker` and `sudo docker` are pointed at different Docker daemons.  If you're on a native-Linux system and `sudo docker ...` works, you don't really need Docker Desktop.

Comment: If I run the command without sudo, the output is:
`❯ docker cp pg:/recom.bkp /dev`

`Successfully copied 32.8kB to /dev`

`open /dev/recom.bkp: permission denied`

Comment: Whoa, don't write into `/dev`, that's a **very bad idea**. See https://www.baeldung.com/linux/dev-directory